# What is the difference between soap_new() and soap_copy()?

Tags: c++, c, web-services, gsoap

What is the difference between:

```
thread_envs[i] = soap_copy(&env);
```

and

```
thread_envs[i] = soap_new();
```

Sould we use one of them or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

`struct soap *soap_new()`

> Allocates, initializes, and returns
>   a pointer to a runtime environment

`struct soap *soap_copy(struct soap *soap)`

> Allocates a new runtime environment
>   and copies contents of the environment
>   such that the new environment does not
>   share any data with the original
>   environment

Comment: "contents of the environment" doesn't include things allocated with soap_malloc(&env), does it ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on your intention: do you want a new, blank environment for each thread (use `soap_new()`) or a separate copy of the existing environment for each thread (use `soap_copy()`).  The process of copying the environment probably has some additional overhead, so all other things being equal, use `soap_new()`.